# SyntaxError: invalid syntax on python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, domoticz

I'm not familiar with Python, but I made the following script with searching on Google.

The script pulls out data from a device and injects it in Domoticz.
When I run the script on my Windows machine, every minute it loops correctly and injects the data into Domoitcz. When I run the same script on my Raspberry Pi, it returns a SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 155) on the except Exception line...

Even if I put a # before that line it raises an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from APSystemsECUR import APSystemsECUR
import time
import asyncio
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib
from pprint import pprint


ecu_ip = "192.168.178.xx"
sleep = 60

url = 'http://192.168.178.xx:8080/json.htm?'
puntcomma = '\u003B'

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ecu = APSystemsECUR(ecu_ip)

while True:
        try:
                data = loop.run_until_complete(ecu.async_query_ecu())
                #pprint(data)

                today_energy_kwh = str(data.get('today_energy')*1000)
                print('Today energy [kWh]: ' + today_energy_kwh)
                getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 212, 'svalue': (today_energy_kwh)}
                webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                #print(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                
                getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 213, 'svalue': data.get('current_power')}
                webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')     
                #print(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                
                getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 195, 'svalue': data.get('timestamp')}
                webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                #print(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
#inverter values
                inverters = data.get('inverters')
#count number of inverters
                Inverter_qty = len(data.get('inverters'))
                print('Inverter_cnt: ' + str(Inverter_qty))
# loop trough all inverters and get the data
                for i in range(Inverter_qty):
                 Inverter = list(inverters.keys())[i]
                 print('InverterId: ' + Inverter)
                 InverterOnline = data['inverters'][Inverter]['online']
                 print('Online: ' + str(InverterOnline))
                 InverterTemperature = data['inverters'][Inverter]['temperature']
                 print('Temperature: ' + str(InverterTemperature))
                 nPower = len(data['inverters'][Inverter]['power'])
                 for x in range(nPower):
                  power = data['inverters'][Inverter]['power'][x]
                  print('Power inverter ' + str(i + 1) + ' panel ' + str(x + 1) + ': ' + str(power) + ' W')

#upload values to Domoticz voor inverter 1
                  if (i == 0) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 173, 'svalue': InverterTemperature}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                   if InverterOnline == True :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 174, 'switchcmd': 'On', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   else :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 174, 'switchcmd': 'Off', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))

#upload values to Domoticz voor inverter 2
                  if (i == 1) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 179, 'svalue': InverterTemperature}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                   if InverterOnline == True :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 180, 'switchcmd': 'On', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   else :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 180, 'switchcmd': 'Off', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))

#upload values to Domoticz voor inverter 3
                  if (i == 2) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 185, 'svalue': InverterTemperature}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                   if InverterOnline == True :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 186, 'switchcmd': 'On', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   else :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 186, 'switchcmd': 'Off', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))

#upload values to Domoticz voor inverter 4
                  if (i == 3) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 191, 'svalue': InverterTemperature}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))
                   if InverterOnline == True :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 192, 'switchcmd': 'On', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   else :
                    getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'switchlight', 'idx': 192, 'switchcmd': 'Off', 'level': 0, 'passcode': '' }
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars))

#upload power values to Domoticz voor inverter 1
                  if (i == 0) and (x == 0) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 196, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 0) and (x == 1) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 197, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 0) and (x == 2) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 198, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 0) and (x == 3) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 199, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')

#upload power values to Domoticz voor inverter 2
                  if (i == 1) and (x == 0) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 200, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 1) and (x == 1) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 201, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 1) and (x == 2) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 202, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 1) and (x == 3) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 203, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')

#upload power values to Domoticz voor inverter 3
                  if (i == 2) and (x == 0) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 204, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 2) and (x == 1) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 205, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 2) and (x == 2) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 206, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 2) and (x == 3) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 207, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')

#upload power values to Domoticz voor inverter 4
                  if (i == 3) and (x == 0) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 208, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 3) and (x == 1) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 209, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 3) and (x == 2) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 210, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')
                  elif (i == 3) and (x == 3) :
                   getVars = {'type' : 'command', 'param' : 'udevice', 'nvalue' : 0, 'idx': 211, 'svalue': (power)}
                   webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url + urllib.parse.urlencode(getVars) + (puntcomma) + '0')


        except Exception as err:
                print(f"[ERROR]", {err})

        #print(f"Sleeping for {sleep} sec")
        time.sleep(sleep)
```

Why does it work on my Windows machine correctly and not on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line raising the error is a `print` statement which is using an f-string (e.g. `f"{variable_name}"`). F-strings were introduced in Python 3.6, so my guess is that your raspberry pi is using a version earlier than that, and your windows machine isn't.

Try checking what version of python is running on your raspberry pi (`python --version` from a terminal). If it's anything earlier than 3.6, the f-strings will cause you syntax errors everywhere in the code.

The only other issue I can think of is you might actually be running python 2.7 with the default `python` command (I can't remember off the top of my head if rasbian does this like some distros). If you get 2.7 with the version check above, try using `python3` and check that version. You will need to be running that script with at least 3.6 for that script to execute.

Incidentally, you have another f-string on line 156, which might explain why if you commented out 155, it raises the exact same syntax error :)